# Mongoose populate not populating and how to give value to populate field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongodb and Nodejs.

I have two collections projects and users.

I want to retrieve name in the login collection based on the `memberId` i will give in the Project collection.I tried the code below, its populating as `null`.

My question is how to give values to `memberId` in `projectModel` in the frontEnd.Beacause it is of type of objectId.I want to pass value to memberId as "sam@gmail.com". Based on this, i want retrieve name from user schema.

Heremy schema :
    UserSchema

```
'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'),
 crypto = require('../lib/crypto');
 var userModel = function () {
 var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  login: { type: String, unique: true },  //Ensure logins are unique.
  password: String, 
  role: String
  });

 userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;
 if (!user.isModified('password')) {
   next();
   return;
     }

    next();
   });

  userSchema.methods.passwordMatches = function (plainText) {
    var user = this;
   return bcrypt.compareSync(plainText, user.password);
    };


    return mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
};
   ProjectSchema

    'use strict';

   var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
   schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var projectModel = function () {

   var projectSchema =  schema({
    projectName: String,
    projectNo: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    releases:String,
    sprintDuration:String,
    sprintCount:String,
        teamname: String,
        teamno: String,
    memberId :
         {type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
    story:            [{
    name: String,
    creator: String,
    date: String,
    desc:String,
    teamMember:String,
    sprintNo: String,
    sprintStartDate: String,
    sprintEndDate: String,
    status: String
    }]
   });
   module.exports = new projectModel();

   router.post('/home', function (req, res) {
    var projectName = req.body.projectName && req.body.projectName.trim();
    var projectNo = req.body.projectNo && req.body.projectNo.trim();
    var memberId = req.body.memberId;
    Project.
        find({})
        .populate('memberId') 
        .exec(function(err, people) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log( people);
    });
```

Comment: you need to reformat your questions, and format your code with code tags

Comment: And I hope you didn't copy/paste your entire code. Please can you give us your entire models files and home function ? (each file in a different code block)

Comment: I want to insert the value "sam@gmail.com" in memberId field of project. Is it possible? but it has type objectId